# Redirected error page show yellow screen of death instead of my content

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to manually redirect an application error like so:

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim routeData = New RouteData()
    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error")
    routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index")

    'route to the error controller, preserving the context
    Dim controller As IController = New Controllers.ErrorController()
    controller.Execute(New RequestContext(New HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData))
End Sub
```

And in my ErrorController I have this action:

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
    'get the exception
    Dim ex = Server.GetLastError()

    ...do something with the exception...

    Return View()
End Function
```

When I do this, even though I'm trying to return a custom view, I just get the YSOD.  If I try to redirect to my controller using `Server.Transfer`, the `Transfer` call fails.  If I try to use `TransferRequest`, it transfers but then `GetLastError` returns null.

So how can I do this transfer so that (1) I can return the view I want and not the YSOD; (2) the last exception is preserved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of research, I made the following changes and now it appears to work:

In the Error event:

```
    Server.ClearError() '<-------------added this line

    Dim routeData = New RouteData()
    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error")
    routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index")
    routeData.Values.Add("exception", Server.GetLastError())  '<-------------added this line

    'route to the error controller, preserving the context
    Dim controller As IController = New Controllers.ErrorController()
    controller.Execute(New RequestContext(New HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData))
```

Changed the action method signature to this:

```
    ' GET: /Error
    Function Index(exception As Exception) As ActionResult
```

This causes the action method to receive the exception object and solves my problem.